# How to use if else condition to change doctype according to the browser in html file.?

Tags: html

We are working on :hover pseudo-class in IE 7, which works only if the docktype is

< !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

,but it decrement the font size of all element

please help me ..

Comment: This is really a question. If you edited the question a bit you might get more responses.

Comment: Solve the font size issues, don't try to hack around them by hacking about with different Doctypes for different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML itself doesn't have any built-in server-side processing. Therefore, it doesn't have the ability to alter itself prior to the response going out.

You have access to javascript, but this is done on the client side, and at that point the browser has already interpreted the doc type.

If you are using a server-side programming language to generate your HTML, then you could include an if statement there, although changing the doctype just so that styling will work correctly is a questionable practice...

Comment: That really limits what you can do. Basically, without a server-side language, you are stuck with displaying a static HTML page.

Comment: There is a solution for your :hover thing, but it doesn't involve the doctype, and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean

> it change the font of text

Changing a Doctype shouldn't affect anything on the page, except how it validates.

Also what do you mean by

> :hover pseudo-class

`:hover` works just fine in IE6

Comment: but not work in IE 7 , and change the font of text means, it decrease all the font size

Comment: It works in all IEs on anchors. If you're trying to make a div have a `:hover` style use jQuery for IE6(http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover). 

As for your font size changing when you change the Doctype, are you setting a default font size on your body? http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

Comment: Why do people down-vote but don't leave a comment as to why they've down-voted? That's just bad form.

Comment: You were probably down-voted because you gave an "answer" that was just more questions.